# Why do I need to provide AWS Credentials when using the Cognito SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My Java app is using AWS Cognito user pools. It uses the Amazon SDK to sign users in. EG:

```
        Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
        authParams.put("USERNAME", email);
        authParams.put("PASSWORD", StringUtils.SPACE);

        AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
            .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
            .withAuthParameters(authParams)
            .withClientId(clientId)
            .withUserPoolId(poolId);

        AdminInitiateAuthResult result = cognitoClient.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
```

This code above will not work without AWS access credentials. Why though? I just want to access the AWS Cognito user pool. Is it absolutely required that I need to pass in AWS credentials into the Java app? Trying to avoid having to either version AWS credentials or manually configure them (or set up some auto-configure mechanism).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [adminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.html#adminInitiateAuth-com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.AdminInitiateAuthRequest-), which is a server-side authentication flow. This is how your credentialed backend would authenticate a user.

For client-side authentication flow, you should use [initiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.html#initiateAuth-com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InitiateAuthRequest-), not adminInitiateAuth.

See [User Pool Authentication Flow](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html) in the Developer Guide.

Comment: Is it possible for backend server code to switch to using `initiateAuth` to sign users in via a cognito user pool?

Comment: I don't see why not, if you have the end user's credentials. In that case the backend is just behaving as a proxy for the client.